# Live USB creating additional partitions

Tags: live-usb, partitioning

Does loading Ubuntu from a live USB create additional partitions? Because, every time I load Ubuntu from a live USB, they create small additional partitions (sda1 in screenshot below)!

[image]

What can I do about it?

Comment: @Takkat Please check the link: http://postimg.org/image/cmet111xn/

Comment: The sda1 drive (Partition).

Comment: It is still a bit unclear at what point this partition appears. Are you shure it was not there before running Ubuntu live? What are the contents of this partition?

Comment: No, i'm able to see these partitions only when I use gparted. And every time I boot using a liveusb, I get to see a new Partition created. So, this doubt arose! Is it usually like this?

Comment: as @Takkat mentions, it's likely those may be hidden partitions, hidden from Windows' view or such, and therefore it already exists (and isn't a brand new partition)

Comment: An Ubuntu live USB will not automatically modify the partition table, but it may do so if you run the installer past a certain point. The partition table you've shown is perfectly valid, although a little unusual. It's impossible to comment on any differences between it and what you see in Windows or what it looked like before without having the "Windows" or "before" view for comparison. Note that some partitioning tools deliberately hide some partitions or show them in different ways, so the fact that two tools show different things isn't a sign of anything being amiss.

Comment: @Rod Smith Thanks for the comment. Now, I'm pretty much sure that ubuntu made the Partition since I used the OS for quite a long time checking it's fluidity and things like that! So, once again thank you!

Comment: If by "the partition" you mean `/dev/sda1` (which you explicitly referred to in your question), that's an extended partition that, in your case, holds an NTFS logical partition. I've never heard of an Ubuntu live disk creating such a setup except under explicit user direction. Perhaps you ran some tools that made this change without understanding what you were doing; or perhaps you're mistaken that the partition is new. The probability of the Ubuntu live disk doing this automatically is essentially 0.

Comment: The reason I doubt this is because, when I had installed Windows the previous day, I clearly remember that there was a system drive and normal drive which was pre created and I split the normal drive and made two partitions, namely c drive and e drive. But the next day when I booted ubuntu using a USB, the e drive which had 700-800gb space, shrunk into a 7gb space and the rest, unallocated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On simply booting an Ubuntu live session from USB our hard-drives will not be touched. We can only read or write to them after they were mounted to the live Ubuntu system. If Windows was hibernated we should however not try to write to any existing Windows partitions to avoid data loss.

Unlike with default Windows tools GParted is able to inspect, and also to change all partitions that reside on our hard drives. This also includes all hidden partitions that were not meant to be used like e.g. custom hibernate partitions, recovery partitions, or other system partitions. In case these partitions were not labeled they will just be numbered according to our device naming specifications.

Therefore it appears that the partition you will only see when booting Ubuntu was created from Windows (note that it is NTFS-formatted), and it is used there for purposes we can not tell for sure. Sometimes mounting such a partition to our live Ubuntu may reveal their file content for further clues on their purpose.

> In summary: **don't worry** - the Ubuntu live session won't touch your hard drives unless you explicitely tell it to do so.

Comment: But once when I booted ubuntu using a USB, and restarted the comp with Windows running, one of my drive partitions had split! The drive sda4 here had split into sda4 and sda5 as seen in the image above.